# Java file crashes under bin folder

Tags: java

In my local machine, I have a jdk131_14 folder placed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk131_14\bin. 
When I click on either one of the files under bin folder, such as java.exe, javaw.exe, javac.exe, the message XXXX.exe has stopped workding pop up.

However, I have another java file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin.
But all the files under C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin does not have the message XXXX.exe has stopped workding pop up.

Comment: Educated guess: Did you download and install the 64-bit JDK in the 32-bit folder?

Comment: Hi Elliott, no . It is a 32 bit JDK

Comment: Both those JDKs are ancient.  No one should be running them.

Comment: This looks like operating system specific. I don’t think it’s related to java.

Comment: I don't know what would be achieved by clicking on the exe's. None of those commands will work without command line arguments.  I don't have Windows to try this out, but I would have though that "this application has stopped" was expected behavior.   Try running them from a cmd prompt ...

Comment: If you really want to use that version of Java, May be try uninstalling and installing again. Most probably some binaries might have got corrupted or windows specific registry got messed up.

Comment: Yeah... that's not how you use those executable files under Windows. When I do it, a terminal window pops open for a second, fills with text and closes right away. When trying to launch the executables from command line, I can see that the text that flashed were the usage instructions: `Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...] (to execute a class)` and so on. Your installation of Java is something like 1.5 DECADES old. Perhaps you should consider an upgrade.